# Transpose list items in data view webpart(xslt)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, data-view-web-part

I am working on a sharepoint list with items view like below

```
name    | code  | total   |  date
build1    x1      10        apl-2013
build2    x50     60        may-2013
build3    x90     450       jul-2013
```

For each new items there will be new column depending on date field, and it's workinkg fine with that except sorting ascending or descending.
I have reached on transposing the date field, but I stuck on showing the total field, like shown on the table below,

```
     name    |  code   | apl-2013 |  may-2013 |  jul-2013
    build1     x1           10          60         450
    build2     x50          10          60         450
    build3     x90          10          60         450
```

But I want to get the html out put like this:-

```
name    |  code   | apl-2013 |  may-2013 |  jul-2013
build1     x1        10             0           0
build2     x50        0            60           0
build3     x90        0             0         450
```

Here is the xml for the list

```
<rs:data>
<z:row name='build1' ows_code='x1' ows_total='10' ows_date='string;#apl-2013' />
<z:row name='build2' ows_code='x50' ows_total='60' ows_date='string;#may-2013' />
<z:row name='build3' ows_code='x90' ows_total='450' ows_date='string;#jul-2013' />
</rs:data>
```

I need your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out and got the solution. The dataview sorts, groups(muenchian grouping)  and adds columns for date values, when new item is added.

I add on the top xsl:template before ---<--xsl:template match="/".........)

```
<xsl:key name="Months" match="@ows_date" use="."/>
```

Then at table headers

```
<!----to transpose the date field on table headers-----><xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[generate-id(@ows_date) = generate-id(key('Months', @ows_date)[1])]">
 <xsl:sort select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@ows_date), 1038, 5)" /> 
<th style="text-align: left">
 <xsl:value-of select="@ows_date"/>
 </th>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

on the rowview template

```
<xsl:variable name="currentMonth" select="@ows_date"/>
 <xsl:variable name="currenttotal" select="@ows_total"/>
```

Finally on transposed rows

```
<xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[generate-id(@ows_date) = generate-id(key('Months', @ows_date)[1])]">
 <xsl:sort select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@ows_date), 1038, 5)" />
 <td>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$currentMonth = @ows_date">
      <xsl:value-of select="$currenttotal"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>0%</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </td>
  </xsl:for-each>
```